# Validate the URL referenced in cell

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way for Google Sheets to validate that the path/URL (referenced in a cell) is valid?

I'd like Sheets to scan a column and mark an adjacent column as `true` or `false` depending on whether something exists at that path or not.

Comment: Good questions, but don't try to shoehorn multiple questions into one question post. Your question about local file paths should be in a separate post.

Comment: @Normal: Wasn't looking to get it closed. Just trying to help the Asker get the help they need.

Answer (score 4):

The spreadsheet functions like `importhtml` and `importxml` seem insufficient for this; they throw an error when they can't parse the content in a specified way, which doesn't mean the content is unreachable.

But you can do this [with a script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). For illustration, my script scans the URLs in cells A1:A10, and records the result in B1:B10. Adjust the ranges as you see fit; they can also be fetched as strings from some spreadsheet cells.

```
function validate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var links = sheet.getRange("A1:A10").getValues();
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var code = 0;
    if (/^http/i.test(links[i][0])) {
      try {
        code = UrlFetchApp.fetch(links[i][0]).getResponseCode();
      }
      catch(e) { 
      }
    }
    results.push([code === 200]);
  }    
  sheet.getRange("B1:B10").setValues(results);
}
```

Explanation: each of the supposed links is first checked for sanity: does it begin with `http`? If yes, then an attempt to get HTTP response code is made. This attempt may well fail; hence the try-catch block. The result is recorded as True only if the code is 200.

Sample output:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-------+
| http://www.example.com                  | TRUE  |
| http://www.invalid.example.com          | FALSE |
| http://stackexchange.com                | TRUE  |
| http://google.com                       | TRUE  |
| http://google.com/non-existent-file.pdf | FALSE |
| blah                                    | FALSE |
| nonsense                                | FALSE |
| 1                                       | FALSE |
| 2                                       | FALSE |
| 3                                       | FALSE |
+-----------------------------------------+-------+
```

---

(Technical note: the method `UrlFetchApp.fetch` allows for an option `muteHttpExceptions` that allows it to proceed after getting a failure HTTP code. However, setting this on does not help against DNS lookup errors; this is why I used try-catch instead.)